# Semantic UI form validation doesn't update on real time

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, semantic-ui

So I have this Semantic UI standard form:

```
<form id="signup-form" class="ui form" method="post">
    <div class="field">
        <label>name</label>
        <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label>username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label>email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="two fields">
        <div class="field">
            <label>password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>password repeat</label>
            <input type="password" name="password-repeat" id="password-repeat">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <div class="ui checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" tabindex="0" class="hidden">
            <label>I accept the terms and conditions</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" value="signup" class="ui blue submit button pull-left">Sign Up</button>
    <div class="ui error message"></div>
</form>
```

And this is the validation script I use:

```
<script>
$('#signup-form').form({
    fields: {
        fullname: {
            identifier: 'fullname',
            rules: [
                {
                    type: 'empty',
                    prompt: 'can not be empty'
                }
            ]
        },
        username: {
            identifier: 'username',
            rules: [
                {
                    type: 'empty',
                    prompt: 'can not be empty'
                }
            ]
        },
        email: {
            identifier: 'email',
            rules: [
                {
                    type: 'email',
                    prompt: 'can not be empty'
                }
            ]
        },
        password: {
            identifier: 'password',
            rules: [
                {
                    type: 'empty',
                    prompt: 'can not be empty'
                },
                {
                    //type: 'regExp[/^[a-z0-9_-]{6,16}$/]',
                    type: 'regExp[/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{6,16}$/]',
                    prompt: 'not valid'
                }
            ]
        },
        password_repeat: {
            identifier: 'password-repeat',
            rules: [
                {
                    type: 'match[password]',
                    prompt: 'must match the password'
                }
            ]
        },
        terms: {
            identifier: 'terms',
            rules: [
                {
                    type: 'checked',
                    prompt: 'must accept the rules'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Everything works as expected but one thing. After user hits the submit button semantic ui checks the form against the validation rules and if it succeeds it will allow the form to be submitted BUT if it doesn't, it shows the error messages and **HIDES** the submit button. After that even when user fixes the values of the form, it still shows the errors at the bottom of form and submit button is **STILL** hidden. Using enter key to submit the form works but that's not a very obvious way.

**How do I make sure Semantic UI shows the submit button again after the form is fixed??**

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it doesn't actually hide it. It just overlaps it. A simple Bootstrap like `clearfix` div after the button fixes the problem.

```
<button type="submit" value="signup" class="ui blue submit button pull-left">Sign Up</button>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Where `clearfix` is:

```
.clearfix,
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after,
.container:before,
.container:after,
.container-fluid:before,
.container-fluid:after,
.row:before,
.row:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after,
.container:after,
.container-fluid:after,
.row:after {
    clear: both;
}
```